# Watching for change in select options

Tags: angularjs

I want to disable an input based on number of elements in it (eg. disable in case of only 1 element). Right now I have my eyes on a directive. The reason I went with a directive is that the ng-options often get quite complicated so it would be annoying to copy/paste them with a comparison into an ng-disabled.

My problem is that I cannot listen to the number of options in the select (or at least I couldn't find a way yet). I.e. my idea would have been to do something like so in the link-function. Basic select (auto-disable being my directive):

```
<select name="field1" ng-model="data.field1" ng-options="i.value as i.text for i in values" auto-disable >
  <option disabled value="" style="display: none;">placeholder</option>
</select>
```

and the link method being defined as such:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
  scope.$watch(elem[0].length, function() {
    elem.prop('disabled', elem[0].length <= 1);
  });
}
```

So: Is there some way to watch the elements in a select, or can I somehow access the select's option count easily inside the ng-disabled?

PS: I already tried listening to "data.field1" but that does not work in all cases (eg. if just other values change but the selected value does not).

Comment: D you want to completely disable the `select`when there is only one element?

Comment: yep, and ng-options sadly throws filters at my input data so bad luck :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you need here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/ekn6x0bp/2/) to disable the select when there are less than 2 elements, you don't need a directive just look at the array length:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select name="field1" ng-model="data.field1" ng-options="i.value as i.text for i in values | filter: { valid: true }" ng-disabled="(values |filter: { valid: true }).length < 2">
</div>
```

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.values = 
    [
       {value: 'hello', text: 'world', valid: true},
       {value: 'hello2', text: 'world', valid: false},
       {value: 'hello3', text: 'world', valid: false},
       {value: 'hello4', text: 'world', valid: false},
    ];  
}
```

**EDIT USING DIRECTIVE:**

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">  
    <select id="field1" ng-model="data.field1" ng-options="i.value as i.text for i in values | filter: { valid: true }" auto-disable></select>
</div>
```

JS DIRECTIVE:

```
app.directive('autoDisable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                if ((elm[0].options.length - 1) < 2) {
                    elm.attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Why do you need to subtract 1 from options.length? Because ng-options automatically adds 1 empty option you have to remove from the count.

Hope it helps

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/v8sac0cm/) with the directive:

Comment: That's cute and all, but its not so funny if your ng-options also throws a handful of filters at your data.

Comment: Can you update the fiddle with what you are telling, sorry I cannot get the point.

Comment: You can use the same filter in the ng-disabled, fiddle and answer updated

Comment: For the porposes of the requirement-as-I-have-it, that works. However it means you have to duplicate arbitrarily complex filters every time you want to do this which is not a very satisfying situation.

Comment: Done with the directive, please look at the answer

Comment: holy crap thats awesome :)

Comment: I'm still fiddling around to maybe also get it to work if the data is updated dynamically, but at least you'll get an upvote for giving very useful pointers :)

Comment: Current iteration is http://jsfiddle.net/rb6f845d/, for some reason that does not work in jsfiddle but it works in my app. Possibly because I use angular 1.3.15 and jsfiddle only has 1.2.1.

Comment: it works if you change `elm` with `elem`... http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/rb6f845d/1/